# Query for adding the contents of two table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Table unit_inward

```
id  supplier_inward_id  unit_id supplied_by supplied_qty    supplied_date   created_date      is_processed
427 1929               UI822900   manager      15            2011-07-06     2011-07-26 18:33:37   No
426 1929               UI822900 manager        15            2011-07-06     2011-07-26 18:33:37  No
429 1929               UI988354 manager        35            2011-07-14     2011-07-27 10:49:21  No
428 1929               UI988354 manager        15            2011-07-14     2011-07-27 10:49:21  No
430 1929               UI600839 manager        10            2011-07-15     2011-07-27 10:56:01  No
431 1929               UI600839 manager        10            2011-07-15     2011-07-27 10:56:01  No
432 1929               UI562771 manager        10            2011-07-15     2011-07-27 10:56:01  No
434 1929               UI600839 manager        10            2011-07-18     2011-07-28 12:52:53  No
```

Table unit_inward_details

```
  id    supplier_inward_id  unit_inward_id  barcode     product_unit    assign_volume   total_qty   supplied_date   created_date
  4       1929                427       8904032004628   5                   2             10          2011-07-06    2011-07-26 18:33:37
  3       1929                426       8906032010012   1                   5             5           2011-07-06    2011-07-26 18:33:37
  5       1929                428       8904032004628   5                   1             5           2011-07-14    2011-07-27 10:49:21
  6       1929                429       8906032010135   15                  2             30          2011-07-14    2011-07-27 10:49:21
  7       1929                430       8906032010012   1                   5             5           2011-07-15    2011-07-27 10:56:01
  8       1929                431       8904032004628   5                   1             5           2011-07-15    2011-07-27 10:56:01
  9       1929                432       8904032004628   5                   2             10          2011-07-15    2011-07-27 10:56:01
  11      1929                434       8904032004628   5                   2             10          2011-07-18    2011-07-28 12:52:53
```

I need a query which can add the contents of **product_unit ,assign_volume and total_qty** using the supplied date from this two tables... how to achieve this??? suppose if the created date is

> 2011-07-15

it should show in one row adding up all the sum of the table.Output similar to this table

```
 supplier_inward_id unit_id supplied_qty    supplied_date   is_processed    barcode product_unit    assign_volume   total_qty
  1929          UI600839        10      2011-07-15              No      8906032010012       2       10              10

 1929           UI600839        10      2011-07-18              No      8904032004628       5       2               10
```

Comment: SELECT a.supplier_inward_id, a.unit_id, a.supplied_qty, a.supplied_date,a.is_processed, b.barcode, b.product_unit, b.assign_volume, b.total_qty FROM unit_inward a, unit_inward_details b WHERE a.unit_id = 'UI600839' AND a.supplied_date = b.supplied_date AND a.id=b.unit_inward_id ORDER BY a.id asc limit 0,15

Comment: and what was the error/output?

Comment: not able to add the contents of the similar date....

Comment: You need to formulate your question differently I think as your example does not make a lot of sense.. What is it you want as output? A table grouped by supplied_date with the sum of product_unit, assign_volume and total_qty of all rows with that date?

Comment: @jonhoo... u are correct.. i just need to sum of product_unit, assign_volume and total_qty of all rows with that date?

Answer (score 0):

You Can Query Mnay structs And Query's  in MySql
By UNION

Example:

```
(SELECT *FORM... ) UNION (INSERT INTO ...) UNIO
```